# Regular expression for ussd code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

My text box should only allow valid `ussd` code

Starts with `*`

Ends with `#`

And in the middle only `*` , `#` and `0-9` should be allow.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also Java or Javascript?

Comment: alert(/^([^0-9#*]$/.test(ussd));  trying with this expression but not working.@Rajesh

Comment: Please add any information related to question in question

Comment: I would be inclined to say **"it doesn't exist"** because USSD codes are *unstructured*. Some don't end with a #, some don't start with a *, for example.

Comment: (By convention, USSD uses MMI codes, but there's nothing that explicitly defines their alphabet or their format. It's like a telnet session.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following regex:

```
/^\*[0-9\*#]*[0-9]+[0-9\*#]*#$/
```

#### Rules

- Starts with *
- Can have 0-9, *, #
- Must have at least 1 number
- Ends with #

```js
function validateUSSD(str){
  var regex = /^\*[0-9\*#]*[0-9]+[0-9\*#]*#$/;
  var valid= regex.test(str);
  console.log(str, valid)
  return valid;
}

function handleClick(){
  var val = document.getElementById("ussdNo").value;
  validateUSSD(val)
}

function samlpeTests(){
  validateUSSD("*12344#");
  validateUSSD("*#");
  validateUSSD("****#");
  validateUSSD("12344#");
  validateUSSD("*12344");
  validateUSSD("****5###");
}

samlpeTests();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ussdNo" />
<button onclick="handleClick()">Validate USSD</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Regex:

```
^\*[0-9]+([0-9*#])*#$
```

> The above regex checks for the following:

1. String that begins with a *.
2. Followed by at least one instance of digits and optionally * or #.
3. Ends with a #.

---

In Java script, you can use this to quickly test it out:

```
javascript:alert(/^\*[0-9]+([0-9*#])*#$/.test('*06*#'));
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Extra note: Whilst this matches the OPs description of a USSD, it fails for a broad variety of them (e.g. `##004**16#` is a valid USSD).

Answer (score 0):

This should work `/^\*[0-9\*#]*[0-9]+[0-9\*#]*#$/`

```js
ussd = "*123#";
console.log((/^\*[0-9\*#]*[0-9]+[0-9\*#]*#$/).test(ussd));

ussd = "123#";
console.log((/^\*[0-9\*#]*[0-9]+[0-9\*#]*#$/).test(ussd));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check here it will work for you

- Starts with *
- Ends with #
- can contain *,#, digits
- Atleast one number

```js
function validate(elm){
  val = elm.value;
  if(/^\*[\*\#]*\d+[\*\#]*\#$/.test(val)){
    void(0);
  }
  else{
    alert("Enter Valid value");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onblur="validate(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex works perfect for USSD shortcodes:

Regex Pattern: **/^*[0-9]+(*[0-9]+)*#$/**

Regex will ACCEPT the following

```
*1#
*12#
*123#
*123*1#
*123*12#
*123*12*1#
```

Regex will REJECT the following

```
*
#
*#
**123#
*123##
*123*#
*123*12*#
```

The answer marked as **BEST ANSWER** has limitations as it supports `****5###` which was not desired in my use case. The regex I've provided does not support chaining "`*`" or "`#`" e.g "`**`" or "`##`" shortcodes will be rejected.