# Java USSD code regex pattern

Tags: java, regex, ussd

How can I test a string is a valid ussd code? I was trying to write my own regex but failed.

It should start with `*` symbol followed by any integers or another one `*`. Star symbol can not repeat. It **mustn't** have `**`. And the last symbol must be `#`. Also this symbol is allowed once.

**My tests:**

```
public static final Pattern USSD = Pattern.compile("Pattern here");

System.out.println(USSD.matcher("*123#").matches());     // Must be true
System.out.println(USSD.matcher("*1*2*3#").matches());   // Must be true
System.out.println(USSD.matcher("*1#23#").matches());    // Must be false
System.out.println(USSD.matcher("***123###").matches()); // Must be false
System.out.println(USSD.matcher("*12**3#").matches());   // Must be false
```

**What I've already tried:**

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416034/regular-expression-for-ussd-code-in-javascript) is not what I'm looking for. It allows dual `*` and dual `#`
- `^\*([0-9]|\*?)*#$` doesn't help with dual stars

Comment: Try `"(?:\\*\\d+)+#"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Answer this question and I will mark it as accepted. It worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following regex with `matches()`:

```
(?:\*\d+)+#
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7y0IMv/1).

In Java, declare it as

```
String pattern = "(?:\\*\\d+)+#";
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - (implicit in `matches()`) - start of a string
- `(?:\*\d+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of the sequence of patterns:

  - `\*` - a `*` char
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - (implicit in `matches()`) - end of string.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/aBxpHb):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("*123#","*1*2*3#","*1#23#","***123###","*12**3#");
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?:\\*\\d+)+#");
for (String str : strs) {
    System.out.println(str + ": " + pat.matcher(str).matches());
}
```

Output:

```
*123#: true
*1*2*3#: true
*1#23#: false
***123###: false
*12**3#: false
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `?:` in your regex?

Comment: @GV_FiQst That is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do). Since the value captured by the group is not used, there is no need to store anything the group matches in the memory.